# Can't copy large files to Windows share - Error closing file: Input/output error

Tags: xubuntu, cifs

Using Xubuntu 16.04.4 and I'm copying some large VM files to a Windows share. I get this error with any of the filemanagers I use:
: Error closing file: Input/output error

It seems to choke only on the large files. Destination is NTFS and SMBv1 is turned off.

Here's my fstab entry for the destination with certain parts obfuscated:

```
//ipaddr/share /mnt/share cifs vers=3.0,username=username,password=password,noperm,dir_mode=0777,file_mode=0777,iocharset=utf8,_netdev 0 0
```

I also tried vers=2.1 with the same results.

Using cp gives a "Failed to close" on the large files in addition to the Input/output error.

I'm trying to backup a few VMs so I can clean install 18.04.

Any ideas?

Comment: I don't know, but I would suggest `cp` the file (even as a test) from terminal to see what you get. It could as simple as 'unable to save permissions' or a warning message that causes the close error. There are file size limits (4gb) for msfat so maybe the w-server is enforcing that limit for all files?

Comment: I tried cp and get the same errors. $ cp -R VirtualBox\ VMs/ /mnt/nraygun/VMs
cp: failed to close '/mnt/nraygun/VMs/Xubuntu 16.04.4 original/Xubuntu 16.04.4.vdi': Input/output error

Comment: So wait a minute. It looks like the files copied. But I don't trust their completeness given the errors. It gave the error on all of the large files (multiple gigabytes in size). I'd rather they copied with no errors. Any other ideas?

Comment: I formatted an external drive as ext4 and was able to copy the VMs there with no errors. Must be something going on with CIFS. Standing by for suggestions/solutions for the Windows share issues...

Comment: I tend to always run `cmp` or `diff` post-cp anyway when the data is important. If you don't trust their completeness I'd for sure use cmp/diff/...  If it were me, I'd create file just under 4gb & see if i got errors, then try again with files grown to just over 4gb to see if they crop up (4gb limit), but I haven't delt with windoze servers in years so it may no longer be an issue...  (*you didn't say file size so I'm not sure if this is even an issue for you*)

Comment: The files inside of the VM directory range from 5GB to 12GB, so they are definitely over 4GB. I'll just rely on the ext4 external drive I formatted to back these particular files up, but I want to get to the bottom of why I can't copy these files to my Windows share.

Comment: Just for kicks I reverted back to SMBv1 on the Win10 that serves the shares. The errors went away and I got a clean copy to the shared drive. So it looks like something is wrong with SMBv2/v3. Not even sure where to begin. Performance is slower with SMBv1. Has anyone else had problems with SMBv2/v3 shares?

Comment: @NRaygun: you are not alone. SMB1 seems to work, but it is slow and also disabled by default on current Windows machines.

Answer (score 1):

Faced the same problem on Debian 9.4

It turned out that when installing the version 2.1 you got this error message. But if it is version 2.0 `cp` works just fine.

So try to change your fstab entry to:

```
//ipaddr/share /mnt/share cifs vers=2.0,username=username,password=password,noperm,dir_mode=0777,file_mode=0777,iocharset=utf8,_netdev 0 0
```

Comment: I'm actually facing a very similar problem on Ubuntu 16.04, mount a CIFS export from a freeNAS server. I've tried different options but using vers=2.0 seems to solve this problem. the big difference in the mount is the rsize and wsize that are 1048576 with v3.0 and are 65536 in v2.0. The problem only happens when mounting over a VPN from a VDSL link. When I mount the share from the "local" network, it doesn't matter which SMB version I force, the Error closing file (and vi exit hung up, BTW) never happen.